# I have a problem with the syntax with jdo fitler.add

Tags: java, sql, jdo

I'm having a problem with the syntax in JDO filter add. I've posted the code below. I'm very new to JDO and trying to reverse engineer my way in to this from other working examples in the codebase.

What I'm trying to do is get a list of achievement objects by id that are attached to a product.

I'm getting  "Variable 'achievement' is unbound and cannot be determined" but i'm not sure how the syntax for filter. add works in this case.

```
public Resolution list() {
    Filter filter = em.newFilter();
    Identity identity = getIdentity();

    // apply security restrictions
    if (identity.getSelectedSchoolId() != null){
        Long school = params().getLong("school.id");
        if (school != null){
            filter.add(":allowed.contains(id) || schoolId == :school");
            filter.set("allowed", getSchoolAccess(school).getAchievements());
            filter.set("school", identity.getSelectedSchoolId());
        }else{
            filter.add(":allowed.contains(id) || :schools.contains(schoolId)");
            filter.set("allowed", getUserAccess().getAchievements());
            filter.set("schools", getUserAccess().getSchools());
        }
    }else{
        filter.add("schoolId == null");
    }

    Long categoryId = params().getLong("filter.category");
    if ( categoryId != null && categoryId != 0 ){
        Category filterCategory = params().getEntity("filter.category", Category.class);
        List<Category> categories = categoryManager.getTree(filterCategory);
        List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Category cat : categories){
            ids.add(cat.getId());
        }

        filter.add(":categories.contains(category.id)");
        filter.set("categories", ids);
    }

    // filter by product
    Long productId = params().getLong("filter.product");
    if (productId != null && productId != 0 ){
          Product product = em.get(Product.class, productId);
         List<Achievement> achievements = product.getAchievements();
         System.out.println(achievements);
         List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
         for (Achievement ach : achievements){
                ids.add(ach.getId());
            }
         filter.add(":achievements.contains(achievement.id)");
            filter.set("achievements", ids);     
      }


    Query q = em.newQuery(Achievement.class);
    q.setFilter(filter.toString());
    q.setOrdering("category.key,name");

    // prepare paging 
    Integer limit = params().getInt("limit");
    Integer start = params().getInt("start");

    if ( start == null )
        start = 0;

    if (limit != null)
        q.setRange(start, limit);

    try {
        em.with(Achievement.class, "image", "category");
        List<Achievement> list = (List<Achievement>) q.executeWithMap(filter.args());
        stash().put("list", list);

        mapper().filter(Achievement.class).add("image", "category");
        return json();
    } finally {
        q.closeAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: EntityManager em = EntityManagerFactory.getManager(); which is a class that retrieves objects based on their attributes. That part of the code seems to be working fine my System out is giving me the list of achievements correctly.

Comment: This is also one filter of many that may be applied to the query dependent on user input

Comment: No I just had not checked back in still can't get that solution to work. Approaching getting that data from a different method.

Comment: Dude, you are singularly not helpful, just ignore this and move on with your life.